# IntelliJ does not generate Copy Constructor

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I try to automatically generate a copy constructor with IntelliJ, but I can not select this due to the box is grey out. How do I automatically generate a copy constructor by IntelliJ?

My Java Class

```
public class Parameter {
    public double mA;
    public double mB;
    public double mC;
    public double mD;
    public String mPath;

    public Parameter(double mA, double mB, double mC, double mD, String mPath) {
        super();
        this.mA = mA;
        this.mB = mB;
        this.mC = mC;
        this.mD = mD;
        this.mPath = mPath;
    }

    public Parameter(double mA, double mB, double mC, double mD) {
        this(mA, mB, mC, mD, "");
    }

    public double getA() {
        return mA;
    }
    public double getB() {
        return mB;
    }
    public double getC() {
        return mC;
    }
    public double getD() {
        return mD;
    }
    public String getPath(){
        return mPath;
    }
}
```

The button is grey out.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you disabled that plugin?

Comment: You must have additional plugins. This is not an available option by default. I tested it myself in my IDE.

Answer (score 10):

Generating a copy constructor functionality is not built into IntelliJ IDEA. Perhaps that Generate Copy Constructor action is coming from a plugin?

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is use "create constructor", select all the fields, then manually "tweak" that into a copy constructor by removing all the parameters :)

No plugin required anyway, and still mostly usable, just somewhat painful, but it will at least help you not forget any fields :)

Comment: Quickest way to do that - use ⌘N (macOS), or Alt+Insert (Windows/Linux) for the Generate menu and then select Constructor

Comment: And don't forget to "tweak" the NOT immutable objects (e.g. Date):
this.startDate = new Date(employee.startDate.getTime());